# MATLAB Linear Mapping of Complex Function

Tags: matlab, mapping, symbolic-math

In the `z` plane `(z = x + j*y)`, I have `y = 2x + 4`.

I would like to map in the plane under the mapping `w = 2*z +6`.

My script is as follows:

```
syms x y real
z = x + i*y;
w = 2*z + 6; 
u = real(w)
% u = 2*x + 6
v = imag(w)  
%v = 2*y
```

My Problem is how to insert or substitute `u = 2*x + 6` and `v = 2*y` to the equation `y = 2*x + 4` in MATLAB and solve it for `v`. 
So the answer should be `v = 2*u - 4`.

Comment: Bit confusing... MATLAB has the `subs` function for symbolic substitution, so maybe formulate your problem using that.

Comment: Thanks Amro. I know this subs function. But still, I can not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can solve the problem with the following script

clc; clear all;

syms x y u v real

z = x + i*y;

w = 2*z + 6;

f = real(w) - u % f = 2*x - u + 6

x = solve(f, x) % x = u/2 - 3

f = imag(w) - v % f = 2*y - v

y = solve(f, y)% y = v/2

f = subs(y-2*x-4,{x},{u/2-3}) % f = v/2 - u + 2

v = solve(f, v) % v = 2*u - 4